# Logman flush buffers to file periodically

Tags: ndis, bsod, windows-wpp, logman

I am troubleshooting NDIS miniport filter driver causing BSOD randomly. I enabled driver verifier for my driver. I am also trying to collect my driver trace logs by **logman** using the following command -

> logman create trace myndis -p {MY_GUID} -ct system -f bincirc -max 5000 -o
>   C:\DriverTrace.etl

But the problem is that **logman** is not writing to file unless the trace is **explicitly** stopped. When BSOD occurs, I think tracing is killed instead of stopping by OS which leads my output etl file to be empty.

I tried `-ft ::1` so that buffers can be flushed every 1 second to the file but that does not seem to work. I have also tried `-rt` flag but isn't helpful. How can I achieve **logman** writing to etl file constantly ?